# Is the context necessary in custom hooks?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hooks

According to the Flutter hooks [documentation](https://github.com/rrousselGit/flutter_hooks#how-to-use) on creating custom hooks, the author mentioned an example like the following,

```dart
ValueNotifier<T> useLoggedState<T>(BuildContext context, [T initialData]) {
  final result = useState<T>(initialData);
  useValueChanged(result.value, (_, __) {
    print(result.value);
  });
  return result;
}
```

with the hook consuming the `context` of the widget. That `context` is not used anywhere in the hook, but it is not a dead code according to the linter. So I just want to know if that `context` is necessary or not? and if so, why?

Comment: Have you tried to run your code without context?

Comment: I did, and it is working well even without the presence of context.

Comment: Ok, Suppose In future you need to pass your result into some widgets then with the help of context you can pass the data. Now if it is not needed then you can remove and just pass ```_``` instead.